# Determine who modified the volume (user using buttons or other applications)?

Tags: android, android-intent

I know volume changes by monitoring the system broadcast, but how can I determine if the volume is modified by the user through the volume button or settings or by other applications?

Answer (score 0):

try using handling media buttons, alongside with volume changes broadcast.
If there is volume change, but not key event - app changed volume, if there is volume change and key event - user changed volume using buttons.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons